# data.table, by reference, sweep in j

Tags: r, data.table

```
DT = data.table(Grp1=letters[1:10], Grp2=letters[rep(1:5, 2)], Grp3=letters[rep(1:2, 5)], matrix(1:100, 10))
grp2.cluster.mean = DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=Grp2, .SDcols=-c("Grp1", "Grp3")]
variable.means = DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols=-c("Grp1", "Grp2", "Grp3")]
```

I'm having trouble getting used to the j operator (in DT[ i, j, by ]). I'd like to retrieve normalized values in the matrix section with a function:

(cluster mean - variable mean) / (cluster mean + variable mean)

Using a syntax similar to:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, New.Fxn), by=GrpX, .SDcols=matrix]
```

I'd like to retrieve this WITHOUT using a 'set' function, in other words I need these new values temporarily (for use within another function), and I need to keep the original values(for use with later functions). Its also a very large table in reality, so I'd like to avoid making extra copies of the table.

I've seen questions/answers that used 'set' functions or rowwise sweeps, but this is more of a didactic question, as I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around the data.table syntax. I guess the root of my issue might be an incomplete understanding of how to recycle/use new vales across the colums/rows wile applying functions in j? I'd like to learn how to use it better for more complex functions and grouping operations in the future, so any advice on how to think about/use the data.table operations would be greatly appreciated! (and yes, I've reviewed all of the vignettes... still having trouble with the application...)

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: `grp2.cluster.mean[, Map(function(x,y) (x-y)/(x+y), .SD, variable.means), .SDcols=!"Grp2"]`? If so, maybe you should be using a matrix instead of a data.table? Or maybe a long-form main table like `mDT = melt(DT, id=1:3)`

Comment: The first solution does work, but I've actually been knocking around the idea of using a reference data matrix instead of a data.table, as it does seem more appropriate for the data that it is. My only issue is that in a majority of what I'll be doing, the first step will generally be applied depending on the groups they belong to (ie DT["a", .. on=Grp1, by=c("Grp2", "Grp3")]), which seems well suited for data.tables. Also, we'll be adding many new groupings/values to each observation. Is there a way I could use the utility of a data.table to reference or grab values from a data matrix?

Comment: Re grabbing values from a matrix, I don't know of a way; suspect it might not help with efficiency. Fwiw, working from the long-form table, I'd make the calculations at different levels of aggregation and then join `mDT[, mean(value), by=.(Grp2, variable)][mDT[, mean(value), by=.(variable)], on=.(variable), .(Grp2, variable, res = (x.V1 - i.V1)/(x.V1 + i.V1))]`

Comment: In this case I'm trying to avoid long form transformations. As it stands each row corresponds to a specific observation, and since I'll be sharing this code as a modifiable pipeline, I'd like to keep things as standard as possible. I do appreciate the code suggestion though, long form transformations are something I'm trying to get used to right now.